# Is the domain layer the same thing as the business layer

Tags: design-patterns

In this article  https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html  Martin Fowler mentioned about the domain layer.Is the domain layer the same thing as the business layer.If not , what is the domain layer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, domain layer is business layer.

And, domain layer contains information about the domain. This is the heart of the business software! The state of business objects is held here.

Comment: Dear @Vladimir thank you for your answer. So  what you mean about domain. I mean , Is this a class, an object or entity?

Comment: In general, it is the whole layer... with entities, classes and objects...

Comment: For example, here PHP implementation - https://github.com/cn007b/wall/tree/master/wall/src/ddd/Wall/Domain/Model/Message/Entity you can find `Message` entity in `Domain` layer, but in is only 1 entity... also you can find `DTO`, `Event`, etc...